# Adding classes to an event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to add classes to event. So I use eventContent in CalendarOptions.
But fullcalendar seems to freeze when I use:

```
private eventRenderFunc(info: EventResizeDoneArg | EventDropArg) {
    info.event.setProp('classNames', 'zadanie');
}
```

How can I add custom classes to event in fullcalendar@5 ?

Here is sample: https://codepen.io/piernik/pen/NWNvrpq?editors=0011

Comment: "seems to freeze"...any errors in the browser's Console?

Comment: P.S. how are you linking this function to the calendar? Please show the relevant calendar code.

Comment: Here is sample https://codepen.io/piernik/pen/NWNvrpq?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `evenContent` hook isn't really intended for setting properties of the event object - it's there to help you control the HTML which is rendered from that event object.

Since your're simply adding the same property to every event object rather than directly manipulating the HTML, a more appropriate place for that would be the `eventDataTransform` callback (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform).

```
eventDataTransform: eventTransformFunc,
```

and

```
function eventTransformFunc(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.classNames = "zadanie";
  return event;
}
```

This works nicely - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKzvBjm